# Caught in the Riley Riddle!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

A really simple 'Riley Riddle':

> My first is 5th alphabet
> My second is 5 letter state
> My last will be same even if you rotate
> But overall I am not that great

Comment: Is any of the given answers correct? If not, could you please comment on why not, at least for the voted ones?

Answer (score 6):

You are

> ego

Because:

1. > E is the 5th letter of the alphabet
2. > The number 5 is a g in the letter state
3. > O is the same no matter how much you rotate it
4. > You're stuck with an inferiority complex

Comment: Can you explain the second clue?

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> **AIDS**

1:

> **A** is the 5th letter in "alphabet"

2:

> Idaho has 5 letters and its abbreviation is **ID**

3:

> **S** is the same when rotated 180 degrees

4:

> AIDS sucks and is definitely not great

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this is most likely not the answer given it requires some esoteric knowledge and there is no knowledge tag, but it fits all the clues

Are you an

> Eido  (a genus of moth)

Since -

1. > E is the 5th letter of the alphabet
2. > ID is short for Idaho a 5 letter state
3. > O is the same no matter how much you rotate it
4. > Overall moths are not great (could just be me though)

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer. And, nope, doesn't require any kind of esoteric knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion (and clearly yours too) this riddle is:

> **EASY**

*My first is 5th alphabet*

> The 5th letter of the alphabet is **E**.

*My second is 5 letter state*

> *ASSAM* is a 5-letter state in India. It is often abbreviated to **AS**.

*My last will be same even if you rotate*

> In certain fonts the letter **Y** might be drawn as three evenly spaced lines with angles of 120 degrees between each. This gives it order-3 rotational symmetry since there are 3 orientations in which it can be rotated around its central point and still resemble a 'Y'.

*But overall I am not that great*

> Putting these three parts all together ('overall') something which is **EASY** (E+AS+Y) to achieve isn't really too *great* an obstacle to overcome.

There is an extra clue in the flavour text too:

> You describe it as a '*really simple* Riley Riddle', and of course 'easy' and 'simple' are synonyms. The riddle's answer was practically in front of our face ('caught in the riddle' itself, like the title suggests) which should have made it very **EASY** indeed!

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess:

> **Estates**

*My first is 5th alphabet*

> **E**

*My second is 5 letter state*

> **state** — quite literally

*My last will be same even if you rotate*

> **s** appears the same even when you rotate it

*But overall I am not that great*

> Maybe the **estates** you’re referring to are not that great?

Answer (score 1):

You are a:

> Emo

Fifth letter is:

> E

Five letter states include:

> Maine, Texas, IdahoI assumed you wanted the first letter so Maine made the most sense hence M.

The only letter that can look the same no matter how it is rotated is:

> O a circle (not perfect but you get my point)

Finally:

> Emos are generally not that great because being an emo is associated with being depressed

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> a donkey

Because:

> a is the 5th letter in alphabet
>  5 looks a lot like an S
>  S is the same no matter how you rotate it, as is ss
>  being a donkey isn't a great thing, they are not well respected animals